# OfficeJS deleting headers on load

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I have a simple piece of code that loads headers and then changes some text in them. Recently an issue was reported where the headers are deleted. I've tracked it down to happening on loading the headers for these documents, and it appears they have '**Link to Previous**' selected in the header options. I'm not sure why this would cause it to be deleted as the code up to that point makes no changes. Even this simple snippet causes the same issue.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    var sections = context.document.sections;
    context.load(sections);
    return context.sync().then(function() {
        if (sections !== null) {
            var headers = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < sections.items.length; i++) {
                var header = sections.items[i].getHeader('primary');
                context.load(header);
                headers.push(header);
            }                
            context.sync().then(function() {
                // when you get here all headers are deleted.
            });
        }
    }).then(context.sync);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, what's really happening is that the `LinkToPrevious` setting is being removed. When that happens the content of the original header is removed from that header, which leaves nothing.

I could determine this by alternating the setting from section to section (on/off).

`LinkToPrevious` is not supported in the Office JS API that I can find, which may explain why the setting isn't being respected. I consider this a bug.

The only possibility to work around this that occurs to me would be to work over the Word Open XML for the headers.